# How to Remove Repeating Icons in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ide, icons

I have a problem with eclipse where it seems to repeat a few of my icons multiple times. When I first noticed this problem I had maybe 2-3 repetitions and now as shown below I have around 10+ on certain icons.

I am using Eclipse Neon. Although I've had this problem before upgrading from Eclipse Mars. The one abnormal thing is I have these icons on my bottom bar. If I move them to the top bar though the repetitions do not go away.

I am just wondering if there is any rhyme or reason for this? Also, is it possible just to disable these icons? I don't think I've ever used the icon below to open a terminal.

[image: My Eclipse Toolbar]

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me.

1. Window -> Perspective -> Reset Perspective...
2. Window -> Perspective -> Customize Perspective...
3. Deselect Terminal from the list and click 'OK'

Comment: That worked on my coworkers computer, it removed the single instance of the terminal icon he had. In my eclipse however it did nothing. Since writing posting this question I have gained around 30 new copies of this icon too so it's slowly filling up my bars.